# Buoyant force in a tub filled with multicolour balls

Tags: fluid-dynamics, buoyancy, superfluidity

Would there be a buoyant force on a moving object like a human in a multicoloured balls(say 1cm diameter) filled tub? Or would it be like a superfluid, so that the human would sink right in without significant resistance? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

The "fluidity" of the balls is a function of the friction between them. The buoyant force acting on a person in the tub is a function of their density. Friction is independent of density, therefore the "fluidity" is independent of the buoyant force. If the balls were absolutely frictionless (i.e., if the ball soup was absolutely fluid) then a person in the tub would sink to the bottom if the person weighed more than the balls that they displaced, or they would float to the top if they weighed less.